# fine tune gpt3 with tabular data

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3, fine-tuning, large-language-model

As the title says, how would one fine tune a LLM with tabular data? My initial sense is that LLM are not suited to learn from tabular data unless the tabular data is restructured into grammatical form, and even then, I have reservations about this approach.

Basically the idea is to be able to ask questions specific to the domain of the data, and the responses include specific datapoints from the database.

Thoughts?